# Python cmd over socket, but readline/completion did not work

Tags: python, sockets, unix, autocomplete, readline

I'm trying to build a shell-like interface using python with cmd module, and communications over sockets. Currently I use telnet as client to interact with...

Everything works as expected, but the readline/completion features (cursor keymaps or Tab appear on the screen)
When same code is not over sockets, and uses default stdin/stdout works ok.

Here's the code portion:

```
from cmd import Cmd
import socket

# Cmd shell
class my_shell (Cmd):
    """Simple shell"""
    def __init__(self, SockFile):
        Cmd.__init__(self, stdin=SockFile, stdout=SockFile)
        sys.stdout = SockFile
        self.use_rawinput = False

    def do_bye(self, line):
        return True
    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

def my_worker(Conn):
    try:
        sockFile = Conn.makefile()
        shell = my_shell ( sockFile ) 
        shell.cmdloop() 
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        Conn.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `readline` works with terminal drivers, not sockets.

Comment: My target is a python program, that while it executes, allow network access with an interactive console (with readline completion features) . Is there a different approach (instead of sockets) or a possible workaround?